# Dual Boot issue Ubuntu and XP

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, grub2, bootloader

I partitioned a drive and loaded Ubuntu 13 on an XP machine.
I am learning about the operating systems and trying to make them play together.

My current boot executes as follows:

System powers up,
Grub asks, what do you want to load, Windows or Ubuntu
I choose Ubuntu everything is good. It loads Ubuntu
I choose Windows and it then loads the windows bootloader and asks me to choose again.
Windows or Ubuntu?

While I realize that its a small issue to ask the question twice.
Its not clean so I don't like it.

I would prefer to run Grub and not have windows ask me what to do, but I could also live without grub and just have the windows bootloader ask me, I really dont care.

Bottom line I have two bootloaders running and I only need one.

I read the forums about Fdisk MBR but the command is not recognized.
This doesn't seem like it should be a hard problem but I am striking out.

Any help is appreciated..

Comment: I reviewed the INI as suggested, should I remove the boot.ini? or should I change it somehow?

Comment: Perhaps you should past the contents of boot.ini to your question.

Comment: [boot loader]
timeout=30
default=multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS
[operating systems]
multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS="Microsoft Windows XP Professional" /noexecute=optin /fastdetect
C:\wubildr.mbr = "Ubuntu"

Comment: I deleted all the txt in the boot.ini, and now it no longer asks, but it still looks for the boot.ini at startup. How do I get the machine to stop looking for the boot.ini at startup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the windows bootloader is set to ask at startup: check your boot.ini using msconfig.exe (from start-run... ).

Comment: I resolved the issue. I removed the C:\wubildrmbr = "ubuntu". This cleanly removed the request from the windows startup.